# Why Does PowerShell Keep Loading an Obsolete Module?

Tags: powershell

I created a new work space in Visual Studio Code (VSC) and copied my PowerShell scripts and modules from an old one, then renamed each file. I updated all the **using** and **Import-Module** statements, and verified by a workspace search that there is no mention of the old names in the source code.

But when I ran the script, I got this error:

```
The 'Get-Arguments' command was found in the module 'TchPublisherArguments', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module TchPublisherArguments'.
```

**TchPublisherArguments** is the **obsolete module from the old workspace**. It *should* have been loading the new version, **WebPublisherArguments**.

I ran **Import-Module** as suggested, but it ran with no output, error or otherwise.

So I ran **Uninstall-Module -name TchPublisherArguments**, and the error message went away.

But now when I run the script with the debugger, it works OK at first, but after a few function calls, the debugger traces into the source code from the OLD workspace module. Even stranger, when I click on the function name in the calling line (in the new workspace), it brings up the CORRECT module in the NEW workspace.

When I run **Get-Module -ListAvailable**, it lists **both** the OLD module (TchPublisherArguments) and the NEW module (WebPublisherArguments).

I removed the folder where TchPublisherArguments.psm1 is located from the environment variable **PSModulePath**, signed out, and signed back on. Didn’t help.

I rebooted the machine and and tried running the script one more time. Same error.

I’m running VSC version 1.81.0. My PSVersionTable:

```
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

What causes this behavior? How do I make PowerShell/VSC forget about the old modules/workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I get to blame the `$env:PSModulePath` variable. I had assumed (reasonably, I think) the $env variables showed only values entered by the user in Windows’ System Properties dialog.

That's only partly true. Some, like PSModulePath, also include predefined locations described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath.

So if you’re unlucky enough to store modules there that are only relevant for one script, they’re actually visible to other scripts as well. In my case, the problem took the form of a name conflict (old and new modules with the same function names). It appears these folders are intended only for general purpose modules that could be used in multiple scripts.

Still learning as I go…